How to call Python functions from CAPL?
I have a Python module, say module.py, which has several functions like below.
"""module.py"""
class myclass: 
    def foo(self, arg1: str, arg2: int) -> int: 
        print(f"foo called with args - {arg1}, {arg2}") 
        return arg2;

So far I am able to run a Python script as a whole to some extent. But I want to call foo() from a CAPL function which looks like below.
variables
{
    int return_value;
}

void GetFooResult()
{
    //insert call to python function here and get the return_value
    write(return_value);
}

Is there a way to achieve this? I don't mind if its complicated but I need some elaboration as I am a novice to CANoe.

Do a preliminary research. Create a DLL in C and call it from the CAPL module. See this question and Embedding Python in Another Application.

Thanks for pointing to a solution. However the links provide CAPL-to-C and C-to-Python integrations in isolation. I'm looking for an CAPL-to-Python demonstration that works for my example

Try to implement a prototype(maybe not working), do a preliminary debugging and ask a specfic question with a [mre]. SO is not a free coding service.

As suggested in comments (though harsh they did help me get started, so coming to SO was not a waste after all!) building and using a CAPL-to-C-to-Python DLL is the solution. We might use C++ or any other supported language in place of C but Python embedding in C is well documented.
Below is the procedure:
 Step 1: Add Python embedding code to the sample CAPLdll.cpp. 
Reference link from comments for Python embedding
#include <Python.h>

int32_t CAPLEXPORT CAPLPASCAL capl_foo() {
//Python embedding done here
}


 Step 2: Add an entry in the export table for the above function. 
Reference link from comments for exporting functions
  {"my_foo", (CAPL_FARCALL)capl_foo, "CAPL_DLL", "Python calls", 'L', 0, "", "", {""}},

 Step 3: Build the CAPLdll project 
 Step 4: Call your Python function from the CAPL node
on key 'p'
{
  int result;
  result = my_foo();
  writeLineEx(1,1,"");
  write("Result is %d", result);
}

 Step 5: Run the simulation 
[I] [Program / Model]   Use the keyboard to control the program
[I] [Program / Model]   <1> Direct call of a CAPL Callback function
...
[I] [Program / Model]   <p> Run Py foo
[I] [Program / Model]   <h> Help
[I] [Program / Model]   --------------------------------------------------------------
[*] [Program / Model]   Result is 42
[I] [Program / Model]   
[*] [Program / Model]   Result is 42
[I] [Program / Model]   

